# How to flush rewrite rules on the activation of any plugin

Tags: rewrite-rules

I created a function in functions.php that adds some rewrite rules:

```
function add_rewrite_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule('events/page/([0-9])*/?', 'index.php?pagename=events&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
    [...]   
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

I would like to execute it every time *any* plugin is activated, so if the new rules get overwritten I can restore them automatically.
Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: what happens if someone visits the permalinks settings page (which triggers a flush)? it's not just plugin activation you need to worry about.

Comment: So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add your rewrite rules on the `init` action hook.
2. In your personal activation function, both a) add the rewrite rules and b) flush the rewrite rules. One time. This is the only time you need to flush the rules.

Alternatively, if your rewrite rules can change through user input, then you need to flush them when the rules change, not at any other time. You still need to add them on `init` though.

Comment: I added the rules on the `init` hook. They don't change through user input, but I think they can change if WP core is updated or on the update of some plugins. Should I flush them using the `generate_rewrite_rules` hook or is it unecessary?

Comment: You only need to flush them when they change, period. Adding them on init is fine the rest of the time.

Comment: Clear. How do I automatically flush them when they change?

Answer (score 1):

Hook your function on the `init` hook so it is always present-

```
function wpd_add_rewrite_rules() { 
    add_rewrite_rule('events/page/([0-9])*/?', 'index.php?pagename=events&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

See the [examples in Codex for `flush_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules#Examples) for where to flush rules when you've added them, either in plugin activation or theme switch. *Do not* flush rewrite rules on `init`.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this will work:

```
add_action( 'activated_plugin', function(){

    // your stuff here

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

where the hook `activated_plugin` is fired after a plugin is activated.

Comment: Thanks: it works. I'm wondering how I could get that rule work with `generate_rewrite_rules` hook, so that I'm sure the rule is added after all rewrite rules have been created.

Comment: Did you check out the [`rewrite_rules_array`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array) filter that's fired just after the `generate_rewrite_rules` filter? It filters all the rewrite rules array and "fires after the rewrite rules are generated".